# Mysql query optimization for union all query

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and keen to know what configuration do i need to have to support 50 millions of read  data from mysql 5.7
Mysql server configuration is 125 gb memory and 100 GB disk space.

I want to know what global and threads configuration do i need to set like innodb_buffer size etc to handle high data efficiently.

I am feeding the data into data-tables using php/mysql 5.7 and it is really hectic and taking around 5 mins.

Below is the query,

```
SELECT
`u`.`user_id`,
IF(
    MAX(ac.account_type) = 'ADVERTISER',
    MAX(a.clientname),
    MAX(p.name)
) AS contact_name,
`ac`.`account_type`,
MAX(c.campaignid) AS campaignid,
MAX(c.campaignname) AS campaignname,
MAX(z.zoneid) AS zoneid,
MAX(z.zonename) AS zonename,
MAX(c.clientid) AS clientid,
MAX(s.date_time) AS date_time,
SUM(s.requests) AS total_requests,
SUM(s.impressions) AS total_views,
SUM(s.clicks) AS total_clicks,
SUM(s.conversions) AS total_conversions,
SUM(s.total_revenue) AS total_revenue,
SUM(s.total_basket_value) AS total_basket_value,
SUM(s.total_num_items) AS total_num_items,
MAX(z.delivery) AS delivery
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        interval_start AS date_time,
        creative_id AS ad_id,
        zone_id,
        0 AS impressions,
        0 AS clicks,
        0 AS conversions,
        0 AS requests,
        total_cost * COUNT AS total_revenue,
        0 AS total_basket_value,
        0 AS total_num_items
    FROM
        rv_data_bkt_revenue
    WHERE
        creative_id > 0
    UNION ALL
SELECT
    interval_start AS date_time,
    creative_id AS ad_id,
    zone_id,
    0 AS impressions,
    COUNT AS clicks,
    0 AS conversions,
    0 AS requests,
    0 AS total_revenue,
    0 AS total_basket_value,
    0 AS total_num_items
FROM
    rv_data_bkt_c
WHERE
    creative_id > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    interval_start AS date_time,
    creative_id AS ad_id,
    zone_id,
    COUNT AS impressions,
    0 AS clicks,
    0 AS conversions,
    0 AS requests,
    0 AS total_revenue,
    0 AS total_basket_value,
    0 AS total_num_items
FROM
    rv_data_bkt_m
WHERE
    creative_id > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    MAX(date_time) AS date_time,
    creative_id AS ad_id,
    MAX(zone_id) AS zone_id,
    0 AS impressions,
    0 AS clicks,
    COUNT(creative_id) AS conversions,
    0 AS requests,
    0 AS total_revenue,
    0 AS total_basket_value,
    0 AS total_num_items
FROM
    rv_data_bkt_a
WHERE
    creative_id > 0
GROUP BY
    creative_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        interval_start AS date_time,
        ad_id,
        zone_id,
        impressions,
        clicks,
        conversions,
        requests,
        0 AS total_revenue,
        total_basket_value,
        total_num_items
    FROM
        rv_data_intermediate_ad
    WHERE
        ad_id > 0
) e
) AS s
INNER JOIN rv_zones AS z
ON
    `z`.`zoneid` = `s`.`zone_id`
INNER JOIN rv_banners AS b
ON
    `s`.`ad_id` = `b`.`bannerid`
INNER JOIN rv_campaigns AS c
ON
    `b`.`campaignid` = `c`.`campaignid`
LEFT JOIN rv_affiliates AS p
ON
    `z`.`affiliateid` = `p`.`affiliateid`
LEFT JOIN rv_clients AS a
ON
    `a`.`clientid` = `c`.`clientid`
INNER JOIN rv_users AS u
ON
    `u`.`default_account_id` = `a`.`account_id` OR `u`.`default_account_id` = `p`.`account_id`
INNER JOIN rv_accounts AS ac
ON
    `u`.`default_account_id` = `ac`.`account_id` OR `u`.`default_account_id` = `ac`.`account_id` AND `u`.`default_account_id` IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    `ac`.`account_id` IN(
        '7',
        '9',
        '10'
    )
GROUP BY
    `u`.`user_id`,
    `ac`.`account_type`
```

Comment: that query is taking taking 5 minutes? or loading data is taking 5 minutes?

Comment: show (text!) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all the tables it uses and output of `explain select...` for that query, please

Comment: it is taking 5 mins for query to execute.

Answer (score 0):

a good idea is to create "Temporary Tables" instead of using UNION you just INSERT INTO the Temporary Table so you can use this table later in the subquery, Hope this would help..

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_name
SELECT Field1, Field2, FieldN  FROM original_tableA
LIMIT 0;
INSERT INTO temp_table_name
SELECT Field1, Field2, FieldN
FROM TABLE_B;
INSERT INTO temp_table_name
SELECT Field1, Field2, FieldN
FROM TABLE_B;
```

*/ Here you can Query your  temp_table_name finally you can drop this/*

Comment: Could you convert above query into what you are suggesting, all fieldnames are mentioned, Regards :)